# HTML Email : text getting down in Outlook

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table

Here is my code for displaying text with image.

```html
<table width="220" align="right" style="">
          <tr>
           <td>
            <table align="left" width="100" style="padding: 0; Margin: 0;  Margin-top:15px;">
      <tr>
      
      <td align="right" style="">
       <span style="color:#000000; font-size:14px; ">Powered By</span>      
      </td>
      
      </tr>
     </table>
   
     <table align="left" width="40"  style="padding: 0; Margin: 0; ">
      <tr>
      
      <td align="center">
       <a href="http://facebook.com" style="color:#808080;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:11px;line-height:20.7999992370605px;word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">
        <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="40" height="40" style="vertical-align:middle;">
       </a>
      </td>
      
      </tr>
     </table>
   
     <table align="left" width="50" style=" Margin-top:15px; ">
      <tr>
      
      <td align="right" style="">
       <span style="color:#000000; font-size:14px;">DUMMY </span>         
      </td>
      
      </tr>
     </table>
   
    </td>
   </tr>

   </table>
```

When I see this in Outlook, then the text **dummy** , gets down to the line.

Where m I lacking?
[image: this is the image how it looks in outlook]

PS: I cant' use `inline-block` , `position` , `div`.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what this looks like in outlook?

Comment: yaa sure.. just a minute

Comment: use style `float:left;`

Comment: `float` is not supported in outlook. `Float support has also been dropped`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this code.**

```
<table align="right" style="margin-top:15px; margin-right: 30px;">
        <tr>
            <td align="right" style="width: 100px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:14px; ">Powered By</span>             
            </td>                  
            <td align="center" style="width:40px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <a href="http://facebook.com" style="color:#808080;font-family:Helvetica;font-size:11px;line-height:20.7999992370605px;word-wrap:break-word;font-weight:normal;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://www.hubilo.in/images_for_links/facebook.png" width="40" height="40" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td align="right" style="width: 50px; padding: 0; margin: 0;">
                <span style="color:#000000; font-size:14px;">DUMMY </span>                  
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```